# VBA Cell Format Error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to format a group of cells using a for loop (later a conditional while loop)

I'm getting the error '1004'

Method 'Range' of object "Global' failed

I can't figure out how to convert the cells value to a range value that doesn't throw this error. The Cells(x,y) by itself throws an error as well

Thanks in advance

```
    For row = 2 To 5

    With Range(Cells(row, 5)).Interior
        .Pattern = xlPatternRectangularGradient
        .Gradient.RectangleLeft = 0.5
        .Gradient.RectangleRight = 0.5
        .Gradient.RectangleTop = 0.5
        .Gradient.RectangleBottom = 0.5
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
    End With
    With Range(Cells(row, 5)).Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Range(Cells(row, 5)).Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = -0.250984221930601
    End With

Next row
```

Comment: `Range(Cells(row,5).AddressLocal)`

Comment: Don't use `row` as a variable name. `.Row` is a [Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215505(v=office.11).aspx) of a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx). Use `Dim rw as long` so a) there is no confusion and b) you save yourself a keystroke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `Range()`

Just do `Cells(row, 5).Interior`

```
  For row = 2 To 5

    With Cells(row, 5).Interior
        .Pattern = xlPatternRectangularGradient
        .Gradient.RectangleLeft = 0.5
        .Gradient.RectangleRight = 0.5
        .Gradient.RectangleTop = 0.5
        .Gradient.RectangleBottom = 0.5
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
    End With
    With Cells(row, 5).Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Cells(row, 5).Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = -0.250984221930601
    End With

Next row
```

Comment: Would it be prudent to correct the OP's improper declaration of a range's [Row property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215505(v=office.11).aspx) as a variable name?

Comment: My school of thought is that it is NEVER proper to use a reserved word as a variable name. If somewhere in the same sub a call was made to `Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row`, the `.Row` would be changed to `.row` and it is more than likely that an error would be thrown rather than supplying the `.Row` property of the range; certainly unlikely that the correct number would be passed back.

Comment: no error....   `Sub test()

   Cells(10, 1).Select

    For row = 1 To 5
        rw = ActiveCell.row
    
    MsgBox row & "<>" & rw
    Next row
End Sub`

Comment: Your example holds true. I guess the range parent resolved the ambiguity. I'll stick with my canonical practise of not using reserved words for variable names and report back if I play around with this some more and come up with a MCVE of 'why not' rather than simply 'bad form'.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you even looping?

```
Sub SO()

    With Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(5, 5)).Interior
        .Pattern = xlPatternRectangularGradient
        .Gradient.RectangleLeft = 0.5
        .Gradient.RectangleRight = 0.5
        .Gradient.RectangleTop = 0.5
        .Gradient.RectangleBottom = 0.5
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
        With .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = -0.250984221930601
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of of Range()

```
With Cells(row, 5).Interior
```

You want to either use

```
Cells(row, col) 
Cells(2, 5)
```

or

```
Range(addressString)
Range("E2")
```

If you don't put a worksheet object in front of either of them they'll refer to the Activesheet or 'Me' if you're working within a worksheet module.

For reference something like:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
set ws = Thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1")

ws.cells(2, 5)
ws.Range("E2")
```